Inference across named graphs in Fuseki
I am looking for a way to run inference in Jena Fuseki across named graphs, preferably the union graph (i.e. across all of the named graphs).  Is this possible?  Below I have a configuration that will successfully infer triples in the default graph, but not across the named graphs.  Is there a configuration that will perform inference across the named graphs?  If not, what strategy have others employed to get this result?
@prefix :       <http://base/#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix ja:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb2:   <http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#> .

# --- the basic fuseki service (endpoints) with pointer to dataset --
:service_tdb_all  a               fuseki:Service ;
    rdfs:label                    "TDB2 INFER Dev" ;
    #fuseki:dataset                :tdb_dataset_readwrite ;
    fuseki:dataset                :dataset ;
    fuseki:name                   "INFER-Dev" ;
    fuseki:serviceQuery           "query" , "" , "sparql" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore  "get" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadQuads       "" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteQuads  "" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpdate          "" , "update" ;
    fuseki:serviceUpload          "upload" .

# --- define the default graph (with inference) and (later) named graphs ---
:dataset a ja:RDFDataset ;
    ja:defaultGraph :model_inf .

# --- add inference to the default graph ---
:model_inf a ja:InfModel ;
     ja:baseModel :graph ;
     ja:reasoner [
         ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/OWLFBRuleReasoner>
     ] .

:graph rdf:type tdb2:GraphTDB ;
  tdb2:dataset :tdb_dataset_readwrite ;
  tdb2:graphName <urn:x-arq:UnionGraph> ;
  .

:tdb_dataset_readwrite
        a       tdb2:DatasetTDB2 ;
        tdb2:location  "../Fuseki/run/databases/dev" .

